# Drag Drop functionality for windows phone using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, drag-and-drop

I want to implement drag and drop feature for windows phone.

Its a web application which is built by using angularjs framework. There are many directives but unfortunately none of them are working on windows phone browser.

FYI: I am going to phonegap this app

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/
It works on IE, however it is not working in windows 8 phone. I am not able to drag the element.